# C++ CLR error after adding function to .h file

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

I'm not a C++ programmer but rather a "code editor", so I hereby apologize sincerely in advance for the question in general.

For some broadcasting software I am editing a plug-in to give it interoperability between native C/++ and CLR (C#).

The host software: OBS (Open Broadcaster Software) - obsproject.com

The plug-in: CLR Host Plugin - github.com/kc5nra/CLRHostPlugin

What I want to do is exposing functions from OBS to some CLR libraries, the total list of exposible functions can be found here: https://github.com/jp9000/OBS/blob/master/OBSApi/APIInterface.h#L198

Now the plug-in is a proxy between the languages and exposes some of the functionalities named above through API.h/cpp, https://github.com/kc5nra/CLRHostPlugin/blob/master/CLRHostInterop/API.h. ***What I want to do is adding more functions to API.h to expose them to CLR libraries.***

When I add a function in API.h, line 51, it'll give me linker errors.

### The API.h change

```
namespace CLROBS 
{

    public ref class API
    {
    public:
        void AddSettingsPane(SettingsPane^ settingsPane);
        void AddImageSourceFactory(ImageSourceFactory^ imageSourceFactory);
        IntPtr API::GetMainWindowHandle();
        void Log(System::String^ format, ...array<System::Object^> ^arguments);
        System::String^ GetPluginDataPath();
        void SetChangedSettings(bool isChanged);
        int GetMaxFPS();
        void StartStopStream(); // Addition to the original.
    };
};
```

### The API.cpp change

```
#include "OBSApi.h"
#include "API.h"
#include "CLRHostApi.h"
#include "OBSUtils.h"
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
// Default code......
int API::GetMaxFPS()
{
    return ::API->GetMaxFPS();
}
void API::StartStopStream()
{
    OBSStartStopStream();
}
```

### The Error

```
error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131187) : Inconsistent method declarations in duplicated types (types: CLROBS.API; methods: StartStopStream): (0x0600006c). <DIR>\CLRHostPlugin\CLRHostInterop\API.obj  CLRHost.Interop
error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131187) : Inconsistent method declarations in duplicated types (types: CLROBS.API; methods: StartStopStream): (0x0600006c). <DIR>\CLRHostPlugin\CLRHostInterop\AbstractPlugin.obj   CLRHost.Interop
error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D6) : Differing number of methods in duplicated types (CLROBS.API): (0x02000008).   <DIR>\CLRHostPlugin\CLRHostInterop\API.obj  CLRHost.Interop
error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (801311D6) : Differing number of methods in duplicated types (CLROBS.API): (0x02000008).   <DIR>\CLRHostPlugin\CLRHostInterop\AbstractPlugin.obj   CLRHost.Interop
```

The in my eye's odd behaviour doesn't occur when using the plain code

```
namespace CLROBS 
{

    public ref class API
    {
    public:
        void AddSettingsPane(SettingsPane^ settingsPane);
        void AddImageSourceFactory(ImageSourceFactory^ imageSourceFactory);
        IntPtr API::GetMainWindowHandle();
        void Log(System::String^ format, ...array<System::Object^> ^arguments);
        System::String^ GetPluginDataPath();
        void SetChangedSettings(bool isChanged);
        int GetMaxFPS();
        // - commented out - void StartStopStream(); // Addition to the original.
    };
};
```

### Edit

*Added API.cpp snippet*

Even when I comment out OBSStartStopStream(); on API.cpp the error still exist.

#### /Edit

Please assist.

Regards,

MusicDemon

Comment: Did you also modify the implementation (cpp) file? You need to implement the new function, internally calling "OBSStartStopStream" on the native project - otherwise, you will end up with a declaration of a method which isn't existing and you will get linker errors.

Comment: Check the time stamp of those two .obj files.  One of them probably is old and still has the old declaration for the class.  Why it didn't get recompiled is unguessable.  Build + Clean is a random thing to do.

Comment: @DenisGerm I have added the function in API.cpp, please refer to the edited post. Adding the OBSStartStopStream() function to API::GetMaxFPS (See main post) does not error. :(

Comment: @HansPassant I've checked them and removed them, the builds still failed, when I remove the declaration in API.h and the function in API.cpp the build went successfully.

I hope either of you have enough information to come up with new ideas.

Comment: Okay, so I looked over the code and wondered - did you also add/modify the "GetMaxFPS" method? I created a simple test project and added the API, Plugin and AbstractPlugin class, commented out some code (only bodies left) and stumbled across the line "::API->GetMaxFPS" - shouldn't it be "clrHostApi->GetMaxFPS"? Because I can not find a static "GetMaxFPS" method in the API header, also would this lead inconsistent linkage. Oh, and if "OBSStartStopStream" isn't static, it's also missing a pointer to an object, I think.

Comment: Okay - please ignore my last post. I've taken further investigation and saw that "::API" is an external object. I've implemented some more functionality but failed to reproduce the linker errors.. in case somebody want to take a look, check out https://github.com/Lunatix89/snippet-container/tree/master/stackoverflow/OBS (please note that I am using VS2013 instead of VS2010)

Comment: One last thought... could it be that the linker mixes the API class with the external API object due to "using namespace CLROBS" or something?